# AngularJS: Preselecting Options on Multiple Select

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to preselect options on my multiselect. In order to make my case clear, I've made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/2140/).

```
<select ng-model="properties" id="props" multiple 
ng-options="option.name group by option.category for option in options"></select>
```

Unfortunately, I am bound by the way the object is received, so I guess I need the ng-options attribute.

Does anybody have an idea how I can get both 'Captain America' and 'Dr. Doom' selected on load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are super close, two changes. Define the attributes in your controller like this

```
$scope.properties = ["Captain America", "Dr. Doom"];
```

And add a small piece to your ng-options like this

```
ng-options="option.name as option.name group by option.category for option in options"
```

Your option.name as will determine what the saved feature looks like in $scope.properties

Comment: You could also do $scope.properties=["4","9"] and use option.id as option.name

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your controller code to:

```
   function TestCtrl($scope) {

    var myOptions = [{
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Captain America",
        "categoryId": "1",
        "category": "Heroes"
    }, {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Iron Man",
        "categoryId": "1",
        "category": "Heroes"
    }, {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "Magneto",
        "categoryId": "2",
        "category": "Vilains"
    }, {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "Dr. Doom",
        "categoryId": "2",
        "category": "Vilains"
    }];

    $scope.options = myOptions;


    $scope.properties = [myOptions[0], myOptions[3]];
}
```

Explanation: you are setting your selected options (properties) to different instances of the objects than the ones that compose the full list.  Use the same object references as shown above.